# RODBCExt: sqlExecute issue with dates

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I was trying to use parameters in a query but I (or my system) seems to have problem with dates.

I'm connection to a MS SQL Server

and define a specific date I want to handle

`endDate <- '02.08.2015'`

My query looks like this:

```
test <-"SELECT [RDate],[Currency_ID],[Rate],[NRate] 
FROM [dwh].[dbo].FC_CurrencyRate] 
WHERE RDate = ? " 

sqlExecute(myconn,test, endDate)
```

This gives the following error

> Error in sqlExecute(myconn, test, endDate) :
>    22018 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specification
>
> [RODBCext] Error: SQLExecute failed
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In sqlExecute(myconn, test, endDate) :
>    22018 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specification

Then I tried to change the dateformat

```
endDate <- as.Date(endDate, format='%d.%m.%Y')
sqlExecute(myconn,test, endDate)
```

but this leads another error

> Error in sqlExecute(myconn, test, endDate) : 
>    07006 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Restricted data type attribute violation
>
> [RODBCext] Error: SQLBindParameter failed
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In sqlExecute(myconn, test, endDate) :
>   07006 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Restricted data type attribute violation

Is this a typical problem? Are there other types of date format using R?

What i also tried was embracing the question mark ? by quotes as '?'.
This lead to a crash of Rstudio and the query time was way too long.

Any hint is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just spent ages trying to work out how to pass a date through to my DB2 database as parameter using `sqlExecute` in R. I couldn't find a concise answer anywhere and I was getting this type of output:

```
> sql
[1] "select date from date where date = ?"
> sqlExecute(conn, sql, data = as.Date("2015-01-01"))
Error in sqlExecute(conn, sql, data = as.Date("2015-01-01")) : 
  07006 -99999 [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0102E  Invalid conversion. SQLSTATE=07006
[RODBCext] Error: SQLBindParameter failed
```

Reading through the RODBCext documentation I stumbled across this line from Zozlak [Source](https://github.com/zozlak/RODBCext/blob/master/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.Rmd)

> • cast dates using as.character(as.Date(column))

So I gave it a go:

```
> sqlExecute(conn, sql, data = as.character(as.Date("2015-01-01")), fetch = T)
        DATE
1 2015-01-01
```

OMG! It **WORKS**!!!

I hope this helps someone. I can't tell whether this is a consistent solution for different DBMS but for my DB2 connection it works just fine.

Comment: thanks for the info, I'll just assume that this will also work for me. Will try it tomorrow at work.

Comment: I can confirm that it also works for me :) Thank you very much for sharing your information

Comment: It doesn't work for me using MSSQL and NZ client / server locale

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

The date must be passed in a format accepted by your database ODBC driver. [By definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-date-time/data-type-support-for-odbc-date-and-time-improvements#data-formats-strings-and-literals) **`YYYY-MM-DD` should be always supported**.
Depending on your ODBC driver other date formats may (or may not) be supported as well.

As by default R prints `Date` objects according to ISO 8601 which is also `YYYY-MM-DD`
**`as.character(as.Date(yourDate, format='see_as.Date_documentation'))` should do the job.**

#### Why `as.Date(myDate, format='myFormat')` does not work?

- R does not have a separate internal data type for dates. Deep in their souls R dates are numeric vectors storing number of days since 1970-01-01 with the `class` attribute set to 'Date' and the `print.Date()` function displaying them as dates instead of numbers.
- The RODBCext package handles only selected R internal data types: *integer*, *double* (*numeric*) and *character* (and all other R internal data types are cast to *character*).

Now because R dates are internally numbers (of type *numeric*) what is passed to an ODBC driver is what you can see with `as.numeric(as.Date(yourDate))` which clearly does not look like a date for the ODBC driver.

Of course you can say that dates are so commonly used that the RODBCext should take care of R Date objects. In such a case, please fill in an issue on https://github.com/zozlak/RODBCext/issues requesting such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the R language, but my best guess is that maybe it can't convert from a `date` type to a SQL `datetime` type.  You could try converting it to a `datetime` with the [`as.POSIXct`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/as.POSIXlt) function.

Comment: posixct isn't working either and it should be the error 07006, if i remember correctly